# ManyToMany Relationship With Type Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this structure of Entities

```
class Group
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private string $name;
}


class GroupUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @var Group
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="GroupUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private Group $group;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private string $type;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private int $user;

}
```

And there are two types of users. Admins and Clients. There's a ManyToMany relationship between Group and User. And the property in GroupUser $type is saving the Class of either Admin or Client and the property $user is saving the id.

| id | group_id | user | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Entity\Admin |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Entity\Client |

How do I join it using doctrine from the Admin and Client-side? Or maybe someone could point out to some resources how this kind of relationship works on doctrine? As I'm having a hard time googling anything out.
I imagine it could be like a conditional leftJoin, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, you cannot do that on database, because it not safe.
Why is it not safe? because you can have an `id` in the `user` column of `userGroup` table that refer to nothing as it is not linked.

I will write what you should have done, and how you can achieve what you want using your own method:

**What you should have done:**
In your `UserGroup` entities, have 2 columns (`admin` and `client`) which are linked to the related entities. They can be null (`Client` is null and `admin` contain the id of `admin` entity if it is an admin and vice versa). Then you can delete the `type` column

**How to achieve what you using your method:**
As it cannot be done in the database, you will have to do it in some manager. Have a method `getUser` which will check on your `type` attribute and return the associated entity from the current id stored in `$user`

example:

```
    public function getUserFromGroupUser(GroupUser $groupUser){
        if('Entity\Admin' ===$groupUser->getType()){
            return $this->adminRepository->find($groupUser->getUser());
        }
        if('Entity\Client' ===$groupUser->getType()){
            return $this->ClientRepository->find($groupUser->getUser());
        }
        throw new \RuntimeException('the type does not exist');
    }
```

Comment: That's definitely one option, though it's not up to me to change the architecture. 
Still, I think there should be some kind of way to do a conditional leftJoin, like when you only want to get clients you would try and do something like:
leftJoin('c.user', 'u')->andWhere(u.type = Entity\Client)

Comment: you could add a ````->join(Client::class, 'client')->join(Admin::class, 'admin')->where('u.type = Entity\Client AND u.user = client.id')->orWhere('u.type = Entity\AdminAND u.user = admin.id')```